# Android/ASP RESTful API authentication without SSL/HTTPS

Tags: java, android, rest, security, authentication

A common SO question, but no specific solid answers.

**My setup:**

- I have a website running on Classic ASP with backed DB. Unfortunately, no SSL Certs are available
- I have an Android application that will send a Google Volley to request data from the site using a bespoke but simple API

**Currently:**

I am still in testing, privately, so currently I just access the site as such:

- On the app, the user enters a UserId and Password once.
- User navigates to a Fragment which is associated with a specific ASP Page which will return some data
- A Volley is sent to /mysite.com/_api/apage.asp?m=md5hashhereabcdefghijk
- The server searches user records for a matching hash (built on UserID+SALT+pass). On matching record, it uses the found userid as the User's ID
- apage.asp does some sql queries and returns a JSON object
- app receives this JSON response and parses.

**The problem:**

Anyone packet sniffing, or MITM, would be able to plainly see the URLs being accessed (and server responses) and be able to replicate the query via their browser. This is what I'm trying to stop. Any SALTs or secret keys in the app would be easily seen by decompiling the APK.

**Issues:**

I've read all sorts of different solutions, but none of which really fit my environment. I can't use ASP session variables (RESTful being stateless), I cant use HTTPS(SSL/TLS) as there are no Certs on the Server. I can't use an App-based password as this can be decompiled and easily seen.

I appreciate that you will never get something 100% secure, but can only make people disinterested in hacking a system, or not make it worth while.

**Proposed solution:**

I want some feedback/thoughts on the following proposed method:

- Each request will have its own handshake to authenticate the app

This will go as such:

- User opens app for the first time and enters UserID/Password. This will remain with the app until it is uninstalled (or logged out), but I intend to keep the user's app logged in
- User navigates in the app to a Fragment that corresponds with a specific page on the server
- Volley is sent with :

  - UserAgent HTTP header 'some value'
  - generate the same authentication hash for (userid+salt+pass)
  - encrypt this hash with a public key
  - one query string /apage.asp?q=abcdefghijk.... sent to server
  - server decrypts using its private key
  - server checks this hash as I do currently.
  - page returns plaintext JSON values (not encrypted)

The same problem happens here whereby a MITM or sniffer could replicate the URL and get the same information back

**A Second Proposed Solution:**

Would it be better with every request actually starting with a whole handshake?

- App sends volley to server requesting a handshake (HELO)
- Server gross error check with UserAgent HTTP Header
- Server logs the timestamp and IP of the request and generates a unique random code
- App receives this code and builds a new hash using that unique code as a Salt
- App sends second volley to /apage.asp?m=MD5(UserID+UniqueCode+Password)
- Server Gross error check with originating IP, timestamp+-tolerance (30 seconds between the two requests?), UserAgent Request Header.
- APage.asp uses this hash to authenticate the request, providing previous steps have successfully passed.
- APage.asp returns a JSON object, as requested.
- Server flags the log of originating IP/timestamp as EXPIRED, or, just remove the record.

This initial step would make it a lot harder for a sniffer or MITM to replicate the URL calls, as A) Each request would have a randomly returned code B) each code/hash combo can only be used once.

The only thing I can think of is someone decompiles the App, and sees the method of handshake, so could try to replicate this. However, the username/password hash would never match as that is the only thing they cannot get from the hash (as it is salted with the random code)

Thoughts? Could it be improved with some RSA public/private key cryptography? Could I generate my querystring apage.asp?m=abcdeghi..., Generate an MD5 Hash of that, append onto the end, then encrypt before sending?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: "no SSL Certs are available". How ?

Comment: "I can't use ASP session variables (RESTful being stateless)" - why not set a session cookie? Also: please migrate off that server, you are causing yourself unnecessary headache.